# VS Code treats JavaScript files as Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vetur

I have currently started using Typescript and I have been using it for a couple days, everything works fine (Emmet, linting etc...), but when I open up my old projects which are written in JavaScript, vs code is giving me warnings and errors about typing and stuff related to typescript.
somehow Vs Code can't recognize that I am using JavaScript.

PS. i am working on a vue (nuxt) project and Vetur Plugin is handling syntax highlighting, linting etc...

error examples:
'modifyHtml' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)

Property '$store' does not exist on type 'CombinedVueInstance<Record<never, any> & Vue, object, object, object, Record<never, any>>'.Vetur(2339)

This is my settings.js:

```
    {
  "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
  "editor.linkedEditing": true,
  "liveServer.settings.donotVerifyTags": true,
  "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
  "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
  "eslint.format.enable": true,
  "emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascriptreact",
    "vue-html": "html",
    "vue-css": "css",
    "razor": "html",
    "plaintext": "jade"
  },
  "emmet.excludeLanguages": ["markdown"],
  "[dart]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.formatOnType": true,
    "editor.selectionHighlight": false,
    "editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false,
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "editor.tabCompletion": "onlySnippets",
    "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false
  },
  "git.confirmSync": false,
  "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
  "nativescript.analytics.enabled": true,
  "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
  "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
  "java.configuration.checkProjectSettingsExclusions": false,
  "sonarlint.rules": {
    "java:S106": {
      "level": "off"
    },
    "javascript:S1117": {
      "level": "off"
    }
  },
  "workbench.preferredDarkColorTheme": "GitHub Dark",
  "workbench.preferredHighContrastColorTheme": "GitHub Dark",
  "workbench.preferredLightColorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark",
  "[json]": {
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
      "strings": true
    },
    "editor.suggest.insertMode": "replace"
  },
  "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
  "typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
  "vetur.experimental.templateInterpolationService": true,
  "cSpell.userWords": ["vuex"],
  "workbench.colorTheme": "GitHub Dark",
  "vetur.format.defaultFormatterOptions": {
    "js-beautify-html": {
      "wrap_attributes": "force-expand-multiline"
    },
    "prettyhtml": {
      "printWidth": 100,
      "singleQuote": false,
      "wrapAttributes": false,
      "sortAttributes": false
    }
  },
  "files.associations": {
    "*.vue": "vue"
  },
  "eslint.validate": ["javascript", "javascriptreact", "vue"],
  "vetur.grammar.customBlocks": {
    "docs": "md",
    "i18n": "json"
  },
  "window.zoomLevel": -1,
  "json.schemas": []
}
```

[image: This is a screenshot of the error on VS Code]

Comment: Are you using SFC for your old Vue project?

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of your VScode?

Comment: @kissu just uploaded a screenshot

Comment: It's Vetur who's generating the error, you should disable the TS options in the Vetur options. There is one for the templates and another one for scripts, and you shouldn't have these errors anymore.

Comment: Thanks @ZakariaSahmane, it solved the problem...

Answer (score 2):

I think I had the same problem. This took my a while to figure out but I think I have it.
To disable type-checking for JavaScript files, add `checkJs: false` to the `compilerOptions` section of your `jsconfig.json` in the project root directory.

This is my `jsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "include": ["./src/**/*"],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "checkJs": false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have tslint, try disabling it. That might solve the issue, sometimes these errors come in eslint too, though

Answer (score 0):

This is what has worked for me. In my workspace `settings.json`:

```json
{
  "vetur.validation.interpolation": false
}
```

This is my `jsonfig.json` settings:

```json
{
  "include": ["./src/**/*"]
}
```